# How to extend a generic?

Tags: c#, generics, active-directory

I have an Active Directory service I've made to help me manage basic tasks from within an ASP.NET MVC 3 application (although in reality it can be any .NET application since it's in a separate assembly). I have one base interface and class, `IActiveDirectoryService<TPrincipal>` and `ActiveDirectoryService<TPrincipal>`. These get extended one level up to `IUserPrincipalService` and `UserPrincipalService`, like this:

```
IUserPrincipalService : IActiveDirectoryService<UserPrincipal> {
}

UserPrincipalService : ActiveDirectoryService<UserPrincipal>, IUserPrincipalService {
}
```

Using Ninject I create a singleton instance of `IUserPrincipalService` passing in the `PrincipalContext` I want it to use. This works perfectly fine, but I now have to create multiple instances for each OU I want to add users to, and that's not going to work with Ninject because the names will conflict.

I need to find a way to pass into this service the specific OU I want. I thought about extending the interfaces to something like `ICityStateUserPrincipalService : IUserPrincipalService` and changing the constructor with Ninject. The problem with this is that I have to make one of these services for each OU we have right now (which happen to be seven). Also, in the future if we need to add a new OU, I have to make it in AD then create a new interface for it as well.

This just doesn't feel right. It would also have to be done within the ASP.NET MVC 3 application, which feels like it's adding bloat and cheats to it. I can't add it to my assembly which houses the current services because I want to keep that generic in case I need to use it across different projects.

Is there a way to both keep what I have now, and make it extendable so I can pass in the path of a specific OU?

The title of the question is probably not very good at all. I'm open to suggestions for changing it, I just couldn't figure out how to phrase it...

Comment: You can add an IOUProvider interface that is passed in to each service that specifies which OUs are of interest

Comment: @pickles, can you give me a code example? My brain has successfully confused itself over this at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `IOUProvider` interface that gets injected to your services. The IOUProvider interface determines which OUs the `IActiveDirectoryService` should care about.

I stubbed out an example below and left out the `TPrincipal` as I don't think it's relevant to the concept of an `IOUProvider`

```
public interface IOUProvider
{
        IEnumerable<OUInfo> GetOUs();
}    

public interface IActiveDirectoryService
{
    IOUProvider RelevantOUProvider { get; }
    IPrincipal FindPrincipals();
}

public class ActiveDirectoryService : IActiveDirectoryService
{
       public ActiveDirectoryService(IOUProvider relevantOuProvider)
       {
       }
}
```